# Custom Error messages in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to customize error messages for invalid credentials using azure b2c custom policy?

Ideally, we would like to show a different error message for invalid credentials, which is “Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?”. Here the entire message is the hyperlink which should redirect to reset password screen.

P.S: We have changed the error messages using custom policy but facing difficulty in having the hyperlink and redirection to reset the password.

Any insight will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the error messages by modifying [the **UserMessageIf*** settings for the **login-NonInteractive** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/a5350879ec228d11a53bdffd5bedbb1d21af96fb/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L397) as follows:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">Email or password is incorrect.</Item>
  <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Email or password is incorrect.</Item>
  <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Email or password is incorrect.</Item>
  ...
</Metadata>
```

Comment: This answer should work, but appears to currently (June 2021) be broken in some circumstances and you will need to take extra steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178990/azure-b2c-custom-policies-error-message.html

Answer (score 0):

The UserMessageIfInvalidPassword can only hold text, if I am not wrong, so you'll have to resort to workarounds unfortunately. Do you have the reset password mechanism also as a policy/technical profile?

The policies in general link to other policies/technical profiles through links that contain a reference to the ClaimsExchanges. For example, a user SignIn page that has SignUp links at the bottom, will contain a reference to the ClaimsExchange that will be called when the user decides to SignUp instead of SignIn.

In your case, if the password reset mechanism is a separate Policy, it could be possible to convert the policy link to an HTML link, and use the same as the error message for "UserMessageIfInvalidPassword". The policy would show the text, which would be rendered as as an HTML link.

It should also be possible to perform some of this workaround through the JS in the page.